# Weighted logarithmic ranking

Tags: summation, logarithms, scoring-algorithm

I want to have a ranking of players by percentage of shots made, weighted by the total number of shots attempted. The weighting should follow a log scale, so for example

Player A has 100% accuracy, and has shot 5 times

Player B has 90% accuracy, and has shot 50 times

So even though Player B has lower accuracy, in this case you can imagine that he has higher rank (B > A). However, because it's log scale, as the number of shots increases, the weighted effect should matter less, so maybe

Player C has 80% accuracy, and has shot 1000 times

Player D has 75% accuracy, and has shot 2000 times

So even though Player D shot twice as many times, with a pretty good accuracy, he is still ranked lower (C > D).

My question is how can define some function f(percent, num_shots, tuning_var) that I can **tune**, such that the threshold at which number of shots begins to have less of an impact decreases? Would it just be making the rank = percent*log(num_shots * tuning_var) or something like that?

Comment: It seems to me that something like a [Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) fits your needs better.  That has the feature of asymptotically approaching a ceiling...hence doubling from $1000$ has minimal effect.  I'd look at something like percent $\times \;f(num_{shots})$ where $f$ is a logistic function (which has tuning parameters as you'll see from link).

Comment: I would start by trying an approach like the one in http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html.  Basically for each one say, "I'm 95% confident he is better than $x$" and then sort by those lower bounds.